# Lag to previous day

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm attempting to lag data to the previous day in R. However in the dataset there are multiple observations for each day. How do I achieve this?

I have looked at using dplyr to lag the variable and using an if statement to achieve this, however this would require around 8 nested if statements to ensure that all observations are lagged to the previous day.

```
  df <- df %>% dplyr::group_by(HomeTeam) %>% 
 dplyr::arrange(Date) %>%
 dplyr::mutate(Score = ifelse(lag(Date) != Date, lag(Score), 
                          ifelse(lag(Date, n = 2) != lag(Date), 
                                  lag(Score,n = 2), ifelse...)))

df <- data.frame(HomeTeam = c("Wolves", "Wolves", "Wolves"), Date = c("2019-08-20", "2019-08-20", "2019-08-19")
```

Input Data

```
HomeTeam       Date           Score
Wolves         2019-08-20     3
Wolves         2019-08-20     1
Wolves         2019-08-19     4
```

Ouput Data

```
HomeTeam       Date           Score
Wolves         2019-08-20     4
Wolves         2019-08-20     4
Wolves         2019-08-19     NA
```

Solution

```
df <- data.frame(HomeTeam = c("Wolves", "Wolves",             
"Wolves","Wolves","Wolves", "Man Utd", "Man Utd", "Man Utd"), Date =         
c("2019-08-20", "2019-08-20", "2019-08-19", "2019-08-19", "2019-08-15", 
"2019-06-01", "2019-06-01", "2019-04-01"), Score = c(3,1,2,2,4,5,6,7))

df %>% dplyr::mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(Date)%>% 
  dplyr::group_by(HomeTeam) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(lagScore = lag(Score)) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(Date) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Date,HomeTeam) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(lagScore = lagScore[1]) %>%
  dplyr::ungroup()

# A tibble: 8 x 4
#  HomeTeam Date       Score lagScore
#  <fct>    <date>     <dbl>    <dbl>
# Man Utd  2019-04-01     7       NA
# Man Utd  2019-06-01     5        7
# Man Utd  2019-06-01     6        7
# Wolves   2019-08-15     4       NA
# Wolves   2019-08-19     2        4
# Wolves   2019-08-19     2        4
# Wolves   2019-08-20     3        2
# Wolves   2019-08-20     1        2
```

Comment: Please provide example input data and expected output.

Comment: If you have multiple occurrences, have you tried simply subtracting 1 day? If `"Date"` class, then `Date - 1`; if `"POSIXt"` class, then `Date - 60*60*24` will almost always be right.

Comment: One question, just to be clear: When you have more than one observation for the same date, the score variable is always the same in all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are lagging to the *previously occurring* date (that may not be "yesterday"), then try this:

```r
library(dplyr)
set.seed(2)
data.frame(
  id = 1:10,
  Date = Sys.Date() + sort(sample(c(0, 1, 3), size=10, replace=TRUE))
) %>%
  mutate(lagDate = lag(Date)) %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  mutate(lagDate = lagDate[1]) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 10 x 3
#       id Date       lagDate   
#    <int> <date>     <date>    
#  1     1 2019-08-20 NA        
#  2     2 2019-08-20 NA        
#  3     3 2019-08-20 NA        
#  4     4 2019-08-21 2019-08-20
#  5     5 2019-08-21 2019-08-20
#  6     6 2019-08-21 2019-08-20
#  7     7 2019-08-23 2019-08-21
#  8     8 2019-08-23 2019-08-21
#  9     9 2019-08-23 2019-08-21
# 10    10 2019-08-23 2019-08-21
```

---

Seeing a little more, try this:

```r
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text="
HomeTeam       Date           Score
Wolves         2019-08-21     96
Wolves         2019-08-21     97
Wolves         2019-08-20     3
Wolves         2019-08-20     1
Wolves         2019-08-19     4")
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date)

df %>%
  mutate(lagDate = lag(Date)) %>%
  group_by(HomeTeam, Date) %>%
  summarize(lagDate = lagDate[1], Score = Score[1]) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(HomeTeam, Date = lagDate, Score) %>%
  right_join(select(df, -Score), by = c("HomeTeam", "Date"))
# # A tibble: 5 x 3
#   HomeTeam Date       Score
#   <chr>    <date>     <int>
# 1 Wolves   2019-08-21     3
# 2 Wolves   2019-08-21     3
# 3 Wolves   2019-08-20     4
# 4 Wolves   2019-08-20     4
# 5 Wolves   2019-08-19    NA
```

Comment: I think he does not want to lag the date, but the score variable.

Comment: Think this hits the spot.

Comment: ... though I don't think your solution above accommodates multiple dates correctly, since it is lagging on `Score` instead of `Date`.

Comment: Done some testing and I think it now accomodates to multiple dates and multiple teams. What I want to happen is the Score to lag for the previous day and be the same for all matches of that day, hence why I lag the score.

Comment: imagine you have an obseration for `2019-08-21` the lagged score should be 3 or 1, and why?

"Why" is important in order to know if `lagScore[1]` is ok in your solution.

Comment: I see, very good question. What would i need to do to get the last value in the group_by?

Comment: You can try with `dplyr::last()` or `dplyr::first()`

Comment: Brad, I added a row (and tweaked code a little) to show it a little more what's going on.

Comment: My head's a little fried at the moment. As I have realised that I don't mind if the data is lagged on the same day unless it is being used in the test set. Then I would need to apply the methodology above. Something I need to think about which might be achievable if I just use group_by and change the relevant variables using dplyr::first()

Comment: `first` is really just short-hand for `[1]`, not sure how it'll help a lot.

Comment: Is there a way I can use [1] across multiple variables without having to do a separate mutate?

Comment: Not sure what you mean ... if you want to grab the first from multiples, then you need `summarize`, perhaps `summarize_at(vars(var1, var2, var3), ~ .[1])`?